# Continue the Pattern #7

Tags: pattern

Continue the pattern with the answers available.

[image: Continue the Pattern]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This table is built by...

> creating a times table and replacing each number by the number of letters in the English spelling of its name.
>  [image: step-by-step construction of this table]

Therefore, the missing number is...

> 4 (option D).